# View goes behind the soft navigation bar

Tags: android, android-layout

If i am using `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>` view goes behind the soft navigation bar.

See this image

[image]

But after click the button view come back correctly

[image]

What is the issue here.

My layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ttech.kecportal.NewThread">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/post_question"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_btn_bg"
        android:text="Post Question"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/new_thread_note_message">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/question"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/new_thread_edit_text_bg"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Your question"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <com.ttech.kecportal.ui.InstantAutoComplete
            android:id="@+id/subject_code"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/new_thread_edit_text_bg"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/arrow_drop_down"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_drop_down"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Select subject code"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/detail_if_any"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/new_thread_edit_text_bg"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top|start"
            android:hint="Enter detail if any"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:padding="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/new_thread_note_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Read the Guidelines carefully before posting a thread"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/heading_textview" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heading_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="ADD NEW THREAD"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/actionBarColor">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/new_thread_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="New Thread"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/new_thread_back_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_back"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>`
```

Comment: But why are you using <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item> ?

Comment: because i need to hide statusbar.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below code in your `styles.xml` and apply it in your manifest .

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

Comment: well then i suggest you to recheck your layout

Answer (score 0):

Use this one in your class file.

```
private void hideSystemUI() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                     View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    );
}
```